# Should I sort by buffer use when rendering?

Tags: opengl

I'm designing the sorting part of my rendering engine. I know that changing the render target, shader program, texture bindings, and more are expensive and therefore one should sort the draw order based on them to reduce state changes. However, what about sorting based on what index buffer is bound, and which vertex buffers are used for attributes?

I'm confused about these because VAOs are mandatory and they encapsulate all of that state. So should I peek behind the scenes of vertex array objects (VAOs), see what state they set and sort based on it? Or should I just not care in what order VAOs are called?

This is what confuses me so much about vertex array objects. It makes sense to me to not be switching which buffers are in use over and over and yet VAOs just seem to force one to not care about that.

Is there a general vague or not agreed on order on which to sort stuff for rendering/game engines?

I know that binding a buffer simply changes some global state but surely it must be beneficial to the hardware to draw from the same buffer multiple times, maybe some small cache coherency?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While VAOs are mandated in GL 3.1 without `GL_ARB_compatibility` or core 3.2+, you do not have to use them the way they are intended... that is to say, you can bind a single VAO for the duration of your application's lifetime and continue to bind and unbind VBOs, etc. the traditional way if this somehow makes your life easier. Valve is famous for advocating doing this in ***[their presentation on porting the Source engine from D3D to GL](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=btNVfUygvio)***... I tend to disagree with them on some points though. A lot of things that they mention in their presentation make me cringe as someone who has years of experience with ***both*** D3D and OpenGL; they are making suggestions on how to port something to an API they have a minimal working knowledge of.

Getting back to your performance concern though, there can be validation overhead for changing bound resources frequently, so it is actually more than just *"simply changing a global state."* All GL commands have to do validation in order to determine if they need to set an error state. They will validate your input parameters (which is pretty trivial), as well as the state of any resource the command needs to use (this can be complicated).

Other types of GL objects like FBOs, textures and GLSL programs have more rigorous validation and more complicated memory dependencies than buffer objects and vertex arrays do. Swapping a vertex pointer should be cheaper in the grand scheme of things than most other kinds of object bindings, especially since a lot of stuff can be deferred by an implementation until you actually issue a `glDrawElements (...)` command.

Nevertheless, the best way to tackle this problem is just to increase reuse of vertex buffers. Object reuse is pretty high to begin with for vertex buffers, if you have 200 instances of the same opaque model in a scene you can potentially draw all 200 of them back-to-back and never have to change a vertex pointer. Materials tend to change far more frequently than actual vertex buffers, and so you would generally sort your drawing first and foremost by material (sub-sorted by associated states like opaque/translucent, texture(s), shader(s), etc.). You can add another level to batch sorting to draw all batches that share the same vertex data after they have been sorted by material. The ultimate goal is usually to minimize the number of draw commands necessary to complete your frame, and using priority/hierarchy-based sorting with emphasis on material often delivers the best results.

Furthermore, if you can fit multiple LODs of your model into a single vertex buffer, instead of swapping between different vertex buffers sometimes you can just draw different sets of indices or even just a different *range* of indices from a single index buffer. In a very similar way, texture swapping pressure can be alleviated by using packed texture atlases / sprite sheets instead of a single texture object for each texture.

You can definitely squeeze out some performance by reducing the number of changes to vertex array state, but the takeaway message here is that vertex array state is pretty cheap compared to a lot of other states that change frequently. If you can quickly implement a secondary sort to reduce vertex state changes then go for it, but I would not invest a lot of time in anything more sophisticated unless you know it is a bottleneck. Prioritize texture, shader and framebuffer state first as a general rule.